# How to add documentation with type hints in class method declaration in Pycharm 2018.2?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

Let's say I have a class method like below-

```
class BasePreStep:
    def __init__(self, threadpool, release_manifest, service_manifest, upgrade_bundle, system_config):
```

If I add type hint like below then auto-completion works fine in the python file

```
class BasePreStep:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, threadpool, release_manifest, service_manifest, upgrade_bundle, system_config):
        # type: (self, ThreadPool, service_version_pb2.ReleaseManifest, service_version_pb2.ServiceManifest, str, SystemConfig) -> ()
```

But if I add comments like below (as explained [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html)) then the auto-completion does not work in the python file.

class BasePreStep:
    **metaclass** = ABCMeta

```
def __init__(self, threadpool, release_manifest, service_manifest, upgrade_bundle, system_config):
    """

    :param threadpool: Threadpool
    :param release_manifest: service_version_pb2.ReleaseManifest
    :param service_manifest: service_version_pb2.ServiceManifest
    :param upgrade_bundle: str
    :param system_config: SystemConfig
    """
```

Can someone let me know what is the recommended way of adding comment along with type hint in Pycharm?

- Python 2.7
- Pycharm 2018.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`param` in docstrings is treated as a description, not as a type annotation, that's why your second example doesn't work.

You have two options here:

1. Add descriptions and types to docstring:

   ```
   class Class:
       def method(self, p1, p2):
           """

           :param p1: parameter 1
           :type p1: str
           :param p2: parameter 2
           :type p2: str
           """
   ```
2. Add descriptions to docstring and document types in a type comment (which must go before the docstring, otherwise Pycharm won't recognize it).

   ```
   class Class:
       def method(self, p1, p2):
           # type: (str, str) -> None
           """

           :param p1: parameter 1
           :param p2: parameter 2
           """
   ```

Comment: Make sure the types referenced are imported, otherwise PyCharm won't help you -- Threadpool has to be imported.

Comment: If there are many type parameters such that the type hints are little long to cross the PEP recommended line size of 120 as in this case. What is the recommended way to split the type hint?